# How can i block on Nginx an attack like the code below?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, server-side-attacks

The error shows up in error.log and the server suffers from multiple requests like this one.

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: "attacker's ip", request: "GET /random characters.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my server ip"
```

Kindly asking for help.

Comment: Check out this answer https://serverfault.com/a/849859/599646 . It describes how to configure Fail2Ban for what you need.

Comment: Also, see the [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) document regarding Passing Uncontrolled Requests to PHP.